# Is there a name for 2.4 Ghz wireless in mouses, keyboards, etc.?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

Like devices using 802.15 is called Bluetooth, 802.11 is WiFi, 802.16 is WiMAX... Wireless headsets, mouses, keyboards, and the like are just called "Wireless".  But is there a name for the type of wireless besides 2.4 GHz wireless? Cause I think WiFi and bluetooth use the same frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in an IEEE standard as the "S band".  2.4GHz is actually just part of the wider S Band, which covers from 2GHz to 4GHz.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_band):

> Wireless network equipment compatible with IEEE 802.11b and 802.11g
>   standards use the 2.4 GHz section of the **S band**. Digital cordless
>   telephones operate in this band too.